# How do I create a tableless model for active admin in rails 5?

Tags: model, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

We've recently upgraded our Rails app from 4 to 5 and I'm running into a breaking change with tableless models.  In Rails 4, we were using this pattern:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :bar

  def self.columns() @columns ||= []; end
end

ActiveAdmin.register Foo do
  def create
    @page_title = "Foo"
    super
  end
end
```

But, after the rails 5 upgrade, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "foo" does not exist
```

any ideas on how to update our tableless models for Rails 5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `ActiveModel::Naming` and stub out a few methods to get it to work in Rails 5. I found that putting everything in a module made it portable too:

```
class Foo
  include Tableless
  attr_accessor :bar
end

#/lib/tableless.rb
module Tableless
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def self.columns
    @columns ||= []
  end

  def initialize(params)
  end

  def self.find(param)
    true
  end

  def to_model
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/1713#issuecomment-28838869

Comment: @PiersC it's the same requirement but the solution has changed with rails 5